# mysql query - return one row per customer in groups like a for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

My question is: we have records of payments from donors in a table that are in the order they were inputted since 2004. Our new POS software import wizard imports user donations ONE TRANSACTION FOR EACH DONOR PER IMPORT. (Ie., DONOR1:Transaction 1, DONOR2:Transaction 1, etc) I need to export my donation table from MySQL in groups of users sorted by transactions so I can break them up in Excel into groups ready for importing.

So for example if donor_id A has 3 transactions and donor_id B has 1 transaction and  C has 5 transactions the output should look like this:

```
  timestamp       |   donor_id   |    donor_name   |    received_date   |     amount 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| 2005-08-12      |       A      |       joe       |      2004-08-10    |      $1,000 
| 2004-08-01      |       B      |       pete      |      2005-08-01    |        $250
| 2006-09-15      |       C      |       sue       |      2006-09-15    |        $350
| 2006-08-12      |       A      |       joe       |      2005-08-11    |        $250
| 2007-08-08      |       C      |       sue       |      2007-08-08    |        $350
| 2007-07-30      |       A      |       joe       |      2006-07-29    |        $350
| 2008-08-11      |       C      |       sue       |      2008-08-05    |        $350
| 2009-09-01      |       C      |       sue       |      2009-08-31    |        $250
| 2010-08-01      |       C      |       sue       |      2010-08-01    |        $350
```

As you can see a pattern I can edit in Excel has emerged. each time a donor has a transaction, it is put into a grouping of other donors with the same COUNT of transactions. so a donor with 3 transactions is grouped 3 times. the query ends when the donor(s) with the highest number of transactions, has its last transaction outputted as the last grouping.

A-B-C is grouping 1, A-C is grouping 2, A-C is grouping 3, C is grouping 4, C is grouping 5.

Any ideas? Thanks! ~Rich

Comment: can you give us a generic excerpt of the dump the old vendor gave you... sounds like you just need to join your user/donor table to your imported transactions table. or show us the relevant tables you have access to and their structure.

Comment: When Asking questions, try to only include information that is directly relevant to the problem you are trying to solve - it helps us because we don't need to filter out the unimportant stuff

Comment: Just confirming too that an import like Donor1 Transaction1, Donor1 Transaction2 would also work? i.e. the donor can appear more than once in the input file?

Comment: the donation table has donor_id, donor_name, recvd_date, timestamp so you should be able to get the desired results from the table itself.

Comment: havent payed too much attention, sorry for that, it looks like a better solution should exist, yet if you need a for loop functionality you can use a cursor. And if you cant make it as a stored procedure for example you can simply store the result in a temporary table and select it all at the end of the query. Most likely not what you are looking for at the moment but still  ...

Comment: donor1, transaction1, donor1 transaction2, etc will work if each transaction record is separated into distinct columns in the excel sheet (trans1 | user | recvd_date1 | trans2 | user | recvd_date2 etc)

Comment: To Clarify, you are just asking - what would be the query to extract the data from the existing donation table?

Comment: no. I need a query that will put a donor (and associated data) into a grouping of other donors for each transaction they made. so if a donor made 5 transactions, then their name (id) will show up in 5 different groupings. if a donor made 3 transactions then they will only show up in 3 different groups.

Comment: Im sorry, I cant figure out what you have or what you want. I suggest you edit your question with an extract of your input file/tables and an extract of the output the query would generate. Of course don't use actual data but we need something realistic to base our answers on. read [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Comment: updated ... is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

what I think I need is the equiv of a for each row as row loop.

something where it passes over the table, counts the number of times a donor is listed, takes each listing and applies it into a group based on donor*transaction. (first donor listing, second donor listing, etc)

I been researching all over ... do you think I need to use an aggregate?

[found this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I might have it..

Change "mytable" to your table name

```
SET @position := 0;
SET @prev_cat := "";

SELECT timestamp, donor_id, donor_name, received_date, amount, donor_number
FROM (
SELECT
    timestamp,
    donor_id,
    donor_name,
    received_date,
    amount,
    IF(@prev_cat = donor_id, @position := @position + 1, @position := 1) AS donor_number,
    @prev_cat := donor_id
FROM mytable
ORDER BY donor_id ASC
) AS tmp
ORDER BY donor_number, donor_id
```

The inner SELECT numbers the donors with an incrementing variable. It's IF statement resets the variable when it gets to the next donor. The outer ORDER BY sorts them by donor_number then donor_id

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of would be to list one donor at a time, assign an incrementing number to their donation record. Do that for all donors.

Then just sort by "assigned number, donor name"

^ not sure how to assign an incrementing number to each donor though. would be a piece of cake in php ;)

Comment: When posting answers, please try to keep them relevant to the problem/domain

Comment: not sure what you mean, the above would solve the problem, unless I'm reading the problem wrong

Comment: The incrementing number would be a piece of cake in a more modern DBMS as well.